# Unique constraint for TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The following example should not be considered as a real use case. It should only help to understand the question.

```
function myFunc<T1 extends string, T2 extends string>(s1: T1, s2: T2): string {
  return "";
}
```

Is it possible to ensure that `T1` !== `T2`, hence that it is not possible to call `myFunc` like `myFunc("MyValue", "MyValue")`?

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured it out.

```
function myFunc<T1 extends string, T2 extends string>(s1: T1, s2: T2 extends T1 ? never : T2): string {
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Color me surprised, that totally works. Was about to comment that it's not possible until I tried it myself just now. Learned something new today.

Comment: @Andrew How does this color you: https://github.com/sno2/bf